# How can i check the HTML document GET request status?

Tags: javascript, html, http, browser, download

I am doing "window.open(file_url)" to download a file and if a file exists backend returns a Blob which gets downloaded by the browser but if the file doesn't exist then backend returns a JSON error message with request status as 500.

so is there is some way to know that "status" for a page.

I know for AJAX we get the status property but for normal web pages do we have some way to know that status since when the browser makes a request for a page its an HTTP GET and it should have status.

Comment: @vibhor1997a I don't want to make an XHR request to download a file & to check the status.
if a file is too large then to check the status I will be doing the full file download via AJAX then will do a window.open(file_url) to start the download.
even if we make an AJAX request and wait for Blob download, user might not able to see the progress and if he closed the tab the download will stop.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example code. So, you should use it.

```
$.get(url, function(data,status, xhr) {
   alert(xhr.status);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for error as

```
 var test = window.open(file_url)
    test.onError = alert('The specified file was not found. Has it been renamed or 
    removed?');
```